# Do we need to create a hotfix branch for every bug following git flow pricinples?

Tags: git, git-flow

I'm new to git and git flow, but I'm a little confused now that if we need to create a new hotfix branch for every single bug? After googling pretty much, I didn't find a good answer. You know , there could be tens of bugs coming each day after our project went live due to the bad quality of another them from global.

If following the pricinples of git flow strictly, we need to create tens of hotfix branch a day, I do not think it is practical.

So the question is **if we can actually have only ONE hotfix branch to fix all the online bugs or if there is another  better workflow solution to handle such case**? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know anything about Git flow (maybe I should get with the flow), but fixing multiple bugs in a single branch presents all sorts of problems.  It becomes difficult to review bugs individually, and it also becomes hard to make a surgical fix for just one thing.  We always create separate branches for each bug fix.

Comment: Don't know about git flow.
We only use hot fix branch to fix P1 issues. But still we always create branch name as ticket number assigned from Jira. This flow depends on you. You can easily come up with your own solution try it and amend it as necessary. there is no fix solution.

Comment: A branch in git is very cheap, while it lives it costs a file of 41 bytes, afterwards the cost disappears as you delete the branch *and* the file. The cost of such a branch is that perhaps you will have more parallel paths in your repository history but that shouldn't be a problem. I wouldn't think twice about creating a branch per bugfix.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen , hello, maybe I didn't make it clear, I mean if we create a branch for each bug, I suppose we also need to create a test server for that bug to test if the fix is fine, but the problem is there are impossibly so many servers available for testing . If we use only ONE test server, how to get all the bug fixes and deploy to the test server automatically ? You know the CI server like Jenkis needs a fixed git repository url, that means each time  Jenkis can only build and deply a hotfix branch. (due to the length limitation,plese contiune to see the next reply)

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, The other bugs from other branches have to wait until previous one is tested fine and Jenkins git url is changed to the next branch. Actually I think we need to deploy all bug fixes on one test server to test, so that we can do the ingegration test. Each time we delopy and test only one fix is not that reliable becasue other fix can pollute the fix, without integration test, we have no idea if all fixes are going right. I'm not sure how hotfix branch test is done in the real world with git flow because the post A successful Git branching model did not mention it any.

Comment: Hotfix branches are needed when there's a critical bug in production that needs to be fixed asap. If you regularly have multiple critical bugs in production that need to be fixed at the same time, maybe you should consider some extended testing before making a release?

Comment: @1615903, yes, that's our case, we had serveral serverity 1 and tens of serverity 2 defects a day when the release went live before. In this case , in which branch do you think should we fix the tens of serverity 2 defects from production? And what is the test strategies? thanks

Comment: The problem here is that if you have tens of severity 2 (I assume these are high priority but perhaps not mission critical?) **per day** after releasing, then your whole release strategy is wrong. You're asking how to use git flow in this environment and it is surely possible but I can tell you that nobody wrote up their opinion on git flow in order to cope with a situation like that. Your test strategy, if you really want my advice on this, is to test **vastly** more, **before** you release. Your whole release procedure and time before the actual release must be analyzed.

Comment: Hi, @LasseV.Karlsen, I wish the code could be tested vastly beflore going live, but that is out of my control. Could you please elaborate on how to use git flow for so many production defects? I assume you were saying git flow hotfix stragegy was only for few produciton bugs instead of many ones, am I right?  Serverity 2 is less urgent than serverity 1, but they still need to be fixed ASAP in our case. Thanks

Comment: No, sorry, I can't, because no matter what you do it is going to be painful. If you do everything in separate branches you will have lots of overhead because you have so many of them, if you do everything directly on master you will quite often end up with releasing things you don't want to release but it is more of a hassle to back it out again and do it properly. Your main problem, whatever workflow you do, is that you have too many critical defects. Any workflow will be painful because it isn't the workflow around the defects that is broken, it is the sheer number of them.